How to Construct the Theory of Hecke Operators for Maass Forms
I'm trying to find a construction for the theory of Hecke operators for Maass forms that is analgous to the double coset operator construction for modular forms. For modular forms of weight $k$, this is done by defining
$$(T_{p}f)(z) = \left(\left[\Gamma_{1}(N)\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & p \end{pmatrix}\Gamma_{1}(N)\right]_{k}f\right)(z).$$
Does the same defintion work for a Maass form $f$ on say $\Gamma_{0}(N)$ if we set $k = 0$? So for example,if $A(\Gamma_{1}(N))$ is the space of Maass forms on $\Gamma_{1}(N)$, then is a valid defintion of the Hecke operator $T_{p}$ given by
$$(T_{p}f)(z) = \sum_{\beta \in \Gamma_{1}(N)\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 
\\ 0 & p\end{pmatrix}\Gamma_{1}(N)}(\det(\beta))^{-1}f(\beta z),$$
so that one can compute
$$(T_{p}f)(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\left(a_{np}(f)+\chi_{N,0}(p)p^{-1}a_{\frac{n}{p}}(f)\right)\sqrt{y}K_{s-\frac{1}{2}}(2\pi|n|y)e^{2\pi inx}?$$
Do the proofs carry through verbatium and do I also have diamond operators? If not, why can't I define the Hecke operators this way? A reference would also be appreciated.

It's not clear what full path you see, but I would expect that most definitions that work with weight $k$ modular forms would also apply essentially verbatim to Maass forms.
For concrete references, see section 3.12 of Goldfeld's *Automorphic Forms on $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ for a completely explicit working of Hecke operators for weight 0 Maass forms on $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$.
Modular Forms: A classical approach discusses various definitions of Hecke operators and how they interact (and also applies these to Maass forms later).
Iwaniec's Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms also has a sufficiently general description of Hecke operators to apply to Maass forms.
A slightly different presentation (that is equivalent) is in Iwaniec's Spectral Methods of Automorphic Forms, in section 8.5. This is actually more or less a paraphrasing of relevant parts of Atkin, Lehner, and Li's work, but it's applied directly to Maass forms.

The "full path" would be that I want to write down a complete theory of Hecke operators and Atkin–Lehner theory for Maass forms on $\Gamma_{1}(N)$. I'm really just asking if I can do this via Diamond and Shurman's approach if I just set $k = 0$ and have my operators act on Maass forms (possibly with twists by Dirichlet characters). Also, I added a more explicit comment in my post above.
